# How to add child to the parent in firebase sequentially?

Tags: android, json, firebase

I don't know if the title makes sense or not, so I will try to elaborate my problem here.

```
{
"rsvp":[
{"event": "event1","name": "name1","rsvp": "going"},
{"event": "event2","name": "name2","rsvp": "going"}
]
}
```

I would like to store the data in the above mentioned format where if the item comes from the same user it should overwrite but what I am getting now is

```
{ "rsvp": {"event": "event_here","name": "name_here","rsvp": "going"}}
```

and every time the value is getting updated irrespective of the user.

Here is my code implementation

```
    final Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constant.FIREBASE_URL).child("rsvp");
    final HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("rsvp", "going");
    map1.put("name", mUserName);
    map1.put("event", title);
    firebase.setValue(map1);
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong. Thank you.

**Update 1**

I'm aware of the `push()` but while retrieving the data it will be a problem to extract the elements the `push()` gives the `unique tag`. Moreover the `push()`creates instance of each call hence lets say one user performs all three operations it will have three instances of it instead of one.

**My Solution**

Assuming firebase doesn't support what I am looking for here..

Here we have known `UID` as well as the `event` for which I planned on adding the rsvp.

So I have planned on making the data structure the following way,

```
{"rsvp":{"uid1":{"event1":{"status":"going","email":"someemail@email.com"},"event2":
{"status":"maybe","email":"someemail@email.com"}},
"uid1":{"event1":{"status":"going","email":"someemail@email.com"},"event2":
{"status":"maybe","email":"someemail@email.com"}}}}
```

But again this solution has restrictions where I won't be able to fetch other user's data from the another. Where I need to know who all member are going for the event.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase has an unusual of dealing with arrays. That's because arrays are inherently hard to scale in a distributed multi-user system, such as Firebase. If you'd like to learn more, read this section of the [Firebase documentation on arrays and lists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase).

Instead of storing the data in an array (which has numeric, sequential keys), I recommend storing it in a Firebase list. A Firebase list uses alpha-numeric keys. They are still always incrementing though, so just like array indices, they are great for storing sequential data.

```
final Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constant.FIREBASE_URL).child("rsvp");
final HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("rsvp", "going");
map1.put("name", mUserName);
map1.put("event", title);
firebase.push().setValue(map1);
```

The only difference here is that the last line uses `push()` to generate a new child. The key will be a string (currently starting with `-K`) known as a push id. If you'd like to learn more about those, read this blog post on [push ids - the 2^120 ways to ensure unique identifiers](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html).

If you keep using `push().setValue(...)` to add your events to the list, they will show up in the order you added them. Just like with array indices, but now with an approach that will also work when many users are adding events at the same time.

### Update

To *read* all responses for `event1`:

```
Query query = firebase.orderByChild("event").equalTo("event1");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot rsvpSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: rsvpSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
      String rsvp = snapshot.child("rsvp").getValue(String.class);
      System.out.println(name+": "+rsvp);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for replying back. I'm aware of the `push()` but while retrieving the data it will be a problem to extract the elements the `push()` gives the unique tag. Moreover the `push()` creates instance of each call hence lets say one user performs all three operations it will have three instances of it instead of one.

Comment: The above code will create a single node under `rsvp`. If you're having problems reading pushed items, include the code you use to read. I'll add some snippets, but be aware that StackOverflow is not well suited for interactive Q&A sessions.

Answer (score 0):

{ "rsvp": {"id"="id","event": "event_here","name": "name_here","rsvp": "going"}}
Change your json just check with id and if id is store then update data of particular id  otherwise store all data

Comment: Ok so everytime I need to call the json file extract the data and then look if its equal or not. So after that what? The problem is adding  a new item and when push command is used it adds keyword of it's own

Answer (score 0):

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    myRef=database.getReference().push().child("Email");
    myRef.setValue(nameValue);
    String key=myRef.getParent().getKey();
    myRef=database.getReference(key).child("Password");
    myRef.setValue(passwordValue);
```